# Hodge numbers of a cartesian product of copies of $\mathbb{C}P^1$

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

I wonder if some works have been done in the context of cohomology space of projective complex manifolds. Specifically I want to study the Hodge diagrams of $\mathbb{C}P^1\times\mathbb{C}P^1$ and $\mathbb{C}P^1\times\mathbb{C}P^1\times\mathbb{C}P^1$. A reference would be very helpful to get started.

Answer (score 13):

There is an analogue of the Künneth Theorem for Dolbeault cohomology. It can be found on page $105$ of *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris.

If $M$ and $N$ are compact complex manifolds, then we have the following equality of Hodge numbers

$$h^{u, v}(M\times N) = \sum_{\substack{p\, +\, r\, =\, u\\ q\, +\, s\, =\, v}}h^{p,q}(M)h^{r,s}(N).$$

For $\mathbb{CP}^1\times\mathbb{CP}^1$, you should obtain the following Hodge diamond:

\begin{matrix}
  &   & 1 &   &  \\
  & 0 &   & 0 &  \\
0 &   & 2 &   & 0\\
  & 0 &   & 0 &  \\
  &   & 1 &   &
\end{matrix}

For $\mathbb{CP}^1\times\mathbb{CP}^1\times\mathbb{CP}^1$, the Hodge diamond is

\begin{matrix}
  &   &   & 1 &   &   &  \\
  &   & 0 &   & 0 &   &  \\
  & 0 &   & 3 &   & 0 &  \\
0 &   & 0 &   & 0 &   & 0\\
  & 0 &   & 3 &   & 0 &  \\
  &   & 0 &   & 0 &   &  \\
  &   &   & 1 &   &   &
\end{matrix}

You can prove by induction that $h^{k,k}((\mathbb{CP}^1)^n) = \displaystyle\binom{n}{k}$ and for $p \neq q$, $h^{p,q}((\mathbb{CP}^1)^n) = 0$.

Comment: The reference you provide is all I was seeking, thank you!

Comment: You stated that the Kunneth formula holds for complex manifolds, but in the reference cited *compact* complex manifolds are considered. Are you claiming that the compactness assumption is not needed to have a Kunneth formula for $\overline \partial$-cohomology? If so, do you know a reference which states this?

Comment: @Blazej: I meant compact manifolds. I don't know if there is a analogue for non-compact manifolds (for one thing, the Hodge numbers can be infinite).