# Kähler manifold which is not a torus or a curve and has every Hodge number nonzero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Basically title.

What is an example of a compact Kähler manifold $X$ satisfying (1) $X$ is not isomorphic to a compact complex torus and (2) $h^{p,q}(X) \neq 0$ for every Hodge number of $X$ (3) the dimension of $X$ is $\ge 2$?

For a compact complex torus of dimension $n$, $ h^{p, q} = \binom{n}{p} \binom{n}{q} \neq 0 $.

Edit: For curves, the Hodge diamond is obvious and I missed it. Thank you to Tabes Bridges for catching it.

Comment: Doesn't every curve of genus $g \ge 2$ do the trick?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to exclude the one dimensional case too, sorry about that.

Comment: Consider products of compact Riemann surfaces of genus $\ge 2$ and use the analogue of the [Kunneth formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654686/hodge-numbers-of-a-cartesian-product-of-copies-of-mathbbcp1).

Comment: @MoisheKohan great, I was unaware that a Kunneth formula like that holds for Hodge numbers too, thanks. Out of curiosity, are there any other examples that are not products?

Comment: You can blowup any example to obtain a new one. In particular, this produces non-product examples.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese how do the Hodge numbers change after a blow up? I know the plurigenera $ h^{p,0} $ remain invariant after a blow up (in general, invariant under a birational map) but I don't know why the others should remain non-zero?

Comment: If $\tilde{X}$ is the blowup of a compact complex manifold $X$ along a compact complex submanifold $Z$ of codimension $r \geq 2$, then $h^{p,q}(\tilde{X}) = h^{p,q}(X)+\sum_{i=1}^rh^{p-i,q-i}(Z)$; see Main Theorem 1.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06749). In particular, $h^{p,q}(\tilde{X}) \geq h^{p,q}(X)$.

Comment: You might be interested in Schreider's "On the construction problem for Hodge numbers" (https://www.iag.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/iag/homepages/schreieder/publications/CP-Geometry_Topology2015.pdf) where he proves that any legal Hodge diamond you can imagine is the Hodge diamond of some manifold.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon: I don't think that is exactly what is proved there. Under additional conditions, you can realise a row of a formal Hodge diamond, or a formal truncated Hodge diamond by a smooth projective variety. The general realisation problem for Hodge diamonds is open as far as I know. The usual symmetry conditions aren't enough, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/372955/21564) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373621/21564) for example.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese You're right! I summarized the result from memory and got it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Moishe Kohan pointed out in the comments, one can use the Künneth theorem for Dolbeault cohomology to deduce that the product of two or more curves serves as an example as long as the genera aren't all one (in which case you get a torus), or all zero - see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1654686/39599) for the exceptional case.

Moreover, if $X$ is an example of such a manifold, and $Z \subset X$ is a compact complex submanifold with codimension $r \geq 2$, then $\tilde{X}$, the blowup of $X$ along $Z$, is another example. This follows from the fact (Main Theorem $1.1$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06749)) that $$h^{p,q}(\tilde{X}) = h^{p,q}(X) + \sum_{i=1}^rh^{p-i,q-i}(Z) \geq h^{p,q}(X).$$

An example not obtained via the above methods is a [Fano surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_surface) - note, this is not a surface which is Fano, but rather a specific class of surfaces of general type first considered by Fano. They have Hodge diamond

\begin{matrix}
  &   & 1 &   &  \\
  & 5 &   & 5 &  \\
10 &   & 25 &   & 10\\
  & 5 &   & 5 &  \\
  &   & 1 &   &
\end{matrix}